# Проблема при установке Jira на Linux server

Tags: java, linux, jira

При запуске инсталятора выдает ошибку:

```
java/bin/java: Syntax error: end of file unexpected (expecting ")")
```

Стоит
java version "1.8.0_144"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_144-b01)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 25.144-b01, mixed mode)
Ubuntu Xenial (16.04.1 LTS)

На офф сайте Джиры решении смотрел, как и на просторах интернета, но ничего не помогло.

Comment: Такое бывает когда пробуют установть 32bit клиент на 64bit разрядную систему или наоборот

Comment: Ставил atlassian-jira-software-7.5.0-x64.bin и atlassian-jira-software-7.5.0-x32.bin. Даже распаковывал из архива прямо там, но вместо страницы с установкой Jira страница приветствия Tomcat.

Comment: И все же проверьте версию. В том числе для какой версии операционной системы ва качаете дистрибуктив https://www.atlassian.com/software/jira/update

Comment: Там всего 7 вариантов загрузки, так что тяжело ошибится. Может знаете толковый мануал по установке Jira на linux сервер. Пусть даже на английском. А то все возможные комбинации с мануалами/версиями, кажется, перепробувал, но толку 0.

Comment: Так там установка однокнопочная.
Ну вот как вариант 
https://gist.github.com/chaitu87/02d1687ef39bde1a03e5b09ac51af46e

Comment: Да, согласен, однокнопочная. Вот по этому мануалу на локальном веб-сервере все установилось в один клик: https://vjordan.info/log/fpga/installing-a-jira-server-on-a-scaleway-arm-instance.html Но как быть, если Syntax error: end of file unexpected (expecting ")") не позволяеет мне провести установку на корпоративном сервере? Может есть какие нибудь идеи, что доставить, что удалить или проапдейтить?

Comment: @JohnSubut на каком этапе эта ошибка? Когда стартуете sh скрипт?

Comment: После 2-ух строк "Unpacking JRE ... " и "Starting installer ..." выдает "/java:ELF: not found" и "/java: Syntax error: "(" unexpected" 
http://pastenow.ru/80c0be09401e3e2ac52124dbcc317d97

Comment: Если устанавливать x64 то ошибка только одна: http://pastenow.ru/ff6921e05b609b46676034439cf7e437